# Design question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, dns, factory, abstract

I'm building a site using mvc2 and have a structure like follows:

Factory -> Domain.objects -> mvc2

One factory contains an enum for logType, which details the actions which have been applied to an object.
The domain requests the object and supplies it to a MVC2 model, this is passed to a view as IEnumerable Ilog, and the view iterates over it.

My issue is that I want the view to create a link based on the log type, so I have a switch statement in the view which creates this functionality. The switch statement is utilising the enum right back in the repository, but this seems a bit wrong to me: exposing the repository to the view.

Should I encapsulate the Log type in a new IList of objects in the domain? Or is it ok referencing this enum in the repository.

If neither of these are ideal, what is the best solution?

Thanks for any help I might get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to use a view model. A view model is a class which is specially tailored to the needs of the view. So here's a typical workflow for a controller action:

1. Query the repository to fetch some domain objects
2. Map those domain objects to a corresponding view model ([AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could help you here)
3. Pass the view model to the view

So in this scenario the view has no knowledge of any of your domain models. That's in general.

Now for your particular case of generating different links based on the value of the enum I think that writing ifs and switches in a view makes in ugly. Don't you find? So writing a custom HTML helper that will generate the proper link based on the view model would be great especially when your view looks like this:

```
<%= Html.MyLink() %>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin! I think I've been misunderstanding what view models were for. I'd put some logic in a view model that accessed the domain. Should the controller access the domain and pass this information to the specific view model, and then push any results back to the domain?

Comment: @misterjingo, while the view model contains view logic it should not directly access the domain. It's the controller that makes the bridge between the domain and the view model by using a mapping layer. This also works the other way round: you receive a view model as controller action argument, the controller maps this view model back to a model and calls the repository passing the model.

Comment: I put these changes in place and it really tidied up my code. I have one final question though. I use interfaces to pass objects. For example, my domain will call a repository (say user), and will receive an IUser object (the IUser specification resides in repository.users.interface). I figure it's ok for the domain to use this IUser definition. Not wanting my controller or view to have any knowledge of IUser, I had been mapping IUser to domainUser and passing this to the controller. Should this mapping occur in the domain, or in the controller?

Comment: also, if it's ok for the mapping to occur in the domain (if it's not, surely controller would need at least access to repository.users.interface.IUser), is there any issue with models having knowledge of IDomainUser (not it's actual name)? This would save having to remap from domain to controller. *Or* should interfaces all be offloaded to their own assembly, so all levels of the model can access them and pass objects freely?

Answer (score 0):

My thought is that this is one of those great uses for a viewmodel and include that information in the viewmodel.